# When invoking the sizeof operator in the called function, what will happen?

Tags: c, sizeof

```
    void testSizeof(double array[])
    {
        printf ("%i\n", sizeof(array));
    }
```

When calling this function, the output is not the length of the array.

Why?

Then, what are the facts about the output?

Comment: You could have compiled a simple example application and find it out yourself... It is not rocket sience

Comment: It's the size of a pointer in your system. Maybe 32-bit or 64-bit...

Comment: Where did you learn C that the section on `sizeof` wasn't full of warnings about pointer decay?

Comment: @Veger:Your suggestion is good, thx!

Comment: @Cairnarvon:I start learning C by <<Think-C(How to Think Like a Computer Scientist C version)>>. I know this function won't output the length in fact, but don't know why...Now I see, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It returns the size of the `double` pointer, i.e. `sizeof(double*)`.**

When a function takes an argument of type `double[]`, this is exactly the same as taking an argument of type `double*`. The array is said to *decay* into a pointer.

For further explanation, see [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) and the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html).

If the function needs to know the size of the array, you have to pass it explicitly. For example:

```
void testSizeof(double array[10]) {...}
```

or

```
void testSizeof(double array[], size_t array_size) {...}
```

In the first example, the array is also [subject to pointer decay](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryparmsize.html). However, since you already know the size of the array, you wouldn't need to use `sizeof()` to figure it out.

It goes without saying that the second approach is much more flexible than the first.

Comment: The second will be ok, but the first one...(http://codepad.org/5kqzjvib).  Thanks, in fact I wonder what did sizeof operator do when in the fuction define in my qusetion.

Comment: @SimonLi: That's not what I meant. If the function takes `double[20]`, it already knows the array has `20` elements. It doesn't need `sizeof()`. In any case, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Oh, I see! So, in fact the output is sizeof(double *)?